# Support Vector Machine: Feature Transformation

Tags: machine-learning, svm

How do I do the transformation in the test data when I have the trained SVM model in hand? I am trying to simulate the SVM output from mathematical equations and the trained SVM model (using RBF kernel). How do I do that?

In SVM, some of the common kernels used are:

[image]

Here *xi* and *xj* represent two samples. Now if the data has, say 5 samples, does this transformation include all the combination of two samples to generate the transformed feature space, like, x1 and x1, x1 and x2, x1 and x3,..., x4 and x5, x5 and x5.

If data has two features, then a polynomial transformation of order 2 transforms the input to 3 dimensions, as explained her in slide 15 http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ml/lect3.pdf

Now how can be find the similar explantion for the transformation using the RBF kernel? I am trying to write a code for transforming the test data so that i can apply the trained SVM model on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way more complex than that. In short - you **do not** map your data directly into feature space. You simply change the **dot product** to the one induced by the kernel. What happens "inside" SVM when you work with polynomial kernel, each point is actually (indirectly) transformed to `O(d^p)` dimensional space (where d-input data dimension, p-degree of polynomial kernel). From mathematical perspective you work with some (often unknown) projection `phi_K(x)` which has the property that `K(x, y) = <phi_K(x), phi_K(y)>`, and nothing more. In SVM implementations, you do not need actual data representation (as `phi_K(x)` is usually huge, sometimes even infinite, like in RBF case) but instead it needs vector of dot product of your point will each element of the training set.

Thus what you do (in implementations, not from math perspective) is you provide:

- During training whole Gram matrix, `G` defined as `G_ij = K(x_i, x_j)` where `x_i` is i'th training sample
- During testing, when you get new point `y` you provide it to SVM as a vector of dot products `H` such that `H_i = K(y, x_i)`, where again `x_i` are your training points (in fact you just need values for support vectors, but many implementations, like libsvm, actually require vector of the size of the training set - you can simply put 0's for `K(y, x_j)` if `x_j` is not a training vector)

Just remember, that **this is not the same** as training linear SVM "on top" of the above representation. This is just a way implementations usually accept your data, as they need a definition of dot product (function) and it is often easier to pass numbers than functions (but some of them, like scikit-learn SVC module, actually accepts functions as kernel parameter).

So what is RBF kernel? It is actually a mapping from points to *functions space* of normal distributions with means in your training points. And then dot product is just an integral from -inf to +inf from the product of such two functions. Sounds complex? It is  at first sight, but it is a really nice trick, worth understanding!